# Html.Replace is not working in Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have following code:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    var html=fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'/index.htm','utf8');
    var message='Template';
    html.replace('{Message}',message);
    res.end(html);    

}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');
```

And below id html file in which I want to replace `{Message},` but its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>{Message}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get while debugging:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `replace` returns a new string, strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN docs for String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of
>   a pattern replaced by a replacement.

This means that your original string will remain unchanged, and the call to `replace()` will return a new string with the replacement made.

Try updating your code with this line:

```
html = html.replace('{Message}',message);
```

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable, replace returns a new string.

```
html = html.replace('{Message}', message);
```